# Why does this variable expansion with evals produce different numbers of backslashes?

Tags: bash

```
[user@localhost ~]$ declare -p test
declare -- test="eval \\\\\\\\; eval \\\\\\\\;"
[user@localhost ~]$ $test
-bash: \\: command not found
-bash: \: command not found
```

It seems like the second set of backslashes is being parsed twice as much as the first set. This happens for any number of backslashes I add.

Why?

Comment: [Variables hold data. Functions hold code. Don't put code inside variables!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easier to see the problem with `echo`:

```
$ declare -- test="echo \\\\\\\\; echo \\\\\\\\;"
$ $test
\\\\; echo \\\\;
```

As you can see it does not run two `echo` commands, it runs a single `echo` and passes the rest of the string to it. This happens because `$test` does not cause shell code to evaluate. It will instead do word splitting into a so-called simple command and invoke the result.

To get the effect you expected, evaluate it as a shell string:

```
$ eval "$test"
-bash: \: command not found
-bash: \: command not found
```

To reproduce the result without the variable, where one eval invokes the second one with one after interpreting the backslashes:

```
$ 'eval' '\\\\;' 'eval' '\\\\;'
-bash: \\: command not found
-bash: \: command not found

$ eval '\\\\; eval \\\\;'  # Equivalent but more canonical
-bash: \\: command not found
-bash: \: command not found
```